# Taylor polynomial formula superscript meaning

Tags: calculus

In a question I was trying to answer, they gave me this formula:

$T_n(x) = a_0 + a_1(x-c)+a_2(x-c)^2+...+a_n(x-c)^n$

I understand this formula. I was then asked to find the following:

$T_n^{(1)}(c)$

What does the 1 mean? Is it the degree of the taylor series? Sorry if this is a stupid question.

To add more information, the rest of the question goes like this.

Find $T_n(c)$

Find $T_n^{(1)}(c)$

Find $T_n^{(2)}(c)$

Find $T_n^{(3)}(c)$

Find $T_n^{(k)}(c)$

Comment: My guess would be that it represents the first derivative of $T_n$, evaluated at $c$, though this would be more commonly (in my experience) notated as $T_n'(c)$. But this is just a guess: whoever is the source of the original question would know best the intent.

Comment: I added more information! Perhaps this would make the intent clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the "$^{(1)}$" means the first derivative, as [Eevee Trainer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/597568/eevee-trainer)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550966/taylor-polynomial-formula-superscript-meaning/3550972#comment7302188_3550966) indicates. If so, then you get

$$T_n^{(1)}(x) = a_1 + 2a_2(x-c) + 3a_3(x-c)^2 + \ldots + na_n(x - c)^{n-1} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

so the result would be $T_n^{(1)}(c) = a_1$ as all of the terms apart from the first one would be $0$.

As for the higher powers, note if you differentiate \eqref{eq1A} again you get

$$T_n^{(2)}(x) = 2a_2 + 6a_3(x - c) + \ldots + n(n-1)a_n(x - c)^{n-2} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Thus, you would get $T_n^{(2)}(c) = 2a_2$.

In general, for each derivative, you "lose" the first remaining non-zero term, and each other term's coefficient has an extra multiplier of the power, plus the power becomes one less too (so each next coefficient multiplier becomes one less). Thus, in general, you would get $T_n^{(k)}(c) = k!a_k$. As such, you have $T_n^{(3)}(c) = 3!a_3 = 6a_3$ and $T_n^{(4)}(c) = 4!a_4 = 24a_4$.

Comment: I see! Then if the original formula represents a taylor approximation of a polynomial of degree n, why would we derive it multiple times to approximate it?

Comment: @StephenLee That's a good question. I believe you normally would not. Instead, this question is to help you understand better what is going on, plus it can possibly be useful to know if you can determine the Taylor series by other means (e.g., somebody gave it to you, or some other formula allowed you to derive it).